# What is best .htc css3 support for IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css3pie

I used PIE.htc and it looks perfect in IE7, but there's a difference in IE8, so I need the best .htc file to support css3 in IE.

Comment: Instantly blaming CSS3 PIE for something that's IE's fault, hmm.

Comment: I'm not blaming CSS3PIE, I'm blaming IE, because I hate it. I'm just trying to find a css3 htc to run css3 on IE7 and 8 without any difference.

Comment: CSS3 PIE *is the best*. What specific problem are you having? Did you try asking in the forum? http://css3pie.com/forum/

Comment: there's no specific problem, except maybe in IE8 it places all affected elements in the top left corner (position: absolute; I guess), but it's bad to be any difference at all.

Answer (score 2):

CSS3Pie is the best in its class. There are a number of other hacks that do similar things for IE8, but they all work in much the same way, so they'll likely have the same bug.

The solution to your problem is documented in the [CSS3Pie Known Issues](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/) page.

If you get this kind of problem, you need to make sure that the parent elements are `position:relative;` rather than the default (`position:static`). This solves most of the weird layout issues that crop up with Pie.

Setting `zoom:1` in the element also fixes a number of issues that might crop up (see the 'hasLayout' notes in the page linked above), although Pie does set this itself, so you shouldn't need to.

These issues are all caused by bugs in IE, not bugs in Pie -- Pie works hard to work around the various IE issues, but at the end of the day, it is a hack to force modern features into an old browser, so don't be surprised if you have to mess around with it a bit.

If you continue having issues, it would be worth posting the details on the forum on the the CSS3Pie site, as the author is very responsive.

Hope that helps.